# Transaction locking an Insert statement

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have an outer distributed transaction which is locking (Hanging) an insert statement to a table. 
I don't have control over the outer transaction. How to avoid this blocking at the very granular level. I tried to put Transaction Suppress around that insert at .net level. It didn't work.

Please look at the image for detailed information.

Any solution to this kind of issue could be very helpful[image]. I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected if there is a strong crossover between what the two operations are looking at, and aren't in the same transaction. The outer transaction has presumably taken a key-range lock that is causing the block (at a guess the outer transaction is "serializable" isolation-level). There is nothing you can really do here, except:

- enlist/operate in the same transaction, rather than operate outside it
- lower the isolation level of the outer operation, so no key-range lock is generated
- if the outer operation is a *query* (a select, not an insert/update/delete), then use NOLOCK or similar to avoid locking it)

if you can't do any of those things, then you *can't* insert without breaking integrity - so it won't let you. You might want to consider deferring the insert until the outer operation has comlpleted.

Comment: In my code I don't see any inner transaction but from the image do think is there any INSERT statement that is blocking, has transaction around it?                                                            I think there is an insert statement before it

Comment: @Praneeth it doesn't matter if the INSERT operation is in a transaction or not; the point is: the **outer** transaction has a lock that you are conflicting with. You either need to be *inside* that transaction, or you need to wait until that transaction is complete.